# str.at(index) is not working on node.js terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access the value of the third index of a string, I know it can be done with `slice()` and other methods,
I am trying to do it with `at()` method it works on Chrome console but doesn't work on node.js terminal.

**code:**

```
const str = "this is some string"
str.at(2)
```

**error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: str.at is not a function
```

Comment: It's not supported (yet) in Node.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `str.charAt(index)` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at#browser_compatibility

Comment: @h-sifat Because `.charAt()` does not work with negativ index values.

Comment: @Behemoth, Sorry I didn't know about that. What is the use cases for negative index? I just tried it and it always returns undefined!

Comment: @h-sifat That's what I'm saying. .charAt() with arguments of negative value does not get the char from the end of the string (as .at() does) but returns `undefined` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at) method does not exist in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) (yet). However you could just use the array index expression syntax.

```js
const str = "this is some string";
console.log(str[2]);
```

You can basically achieve the same result. The only difference is that [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at) makes it a little easier if you want to get a char at the end of a string:

Using square bracket syntax:

```js
const str = "this is some string";
console.log(str[str.length - 1]);
```

Using [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at)

```js
const str = "this is some string";
console.log(str.at(-1));
```

If you really, really want to, you could also just define your own `String.prototype.at()`:

```js
const str = "this is some string";

String.prototype.at = function (pos) {
  return pos >= 0 ? this[pos] : this[this.length + pos];
};

console.log(str.at(0));   // "t"
console.log(str.at(-1));  // "g"
```